# Django RedirectView with slug in the URL

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I'm getting `RedirectView` with Django and I would like to know how I can pass a slug in my url.

In my Django web application, users can set one or multiple document(s) in a cart and open a modal with personal informations before to submit the form and get an email with checked document(s).

This url in my application looks like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/freepub/home?DocumentChoice=<code>&DocumentSelected=Add+document
```

`<code>` corresponds to a unique document code (ex: `PUBSD15-FR-PDF` or `PUBSD01-EN-EPUB`)

But this url is a bit complicated, because it should be add to another application.

That's why I'm using `RedirectView` in order to make easier this url :

```
url(r'^freepub/direct/download/(?P<code>[\w\.-]+)/', 
       RedirectView.as_view(url="http://localhost:8000/freepub/home?DocumentChoice=(?P<code>[\w\.-]+)&DocumentSelected=Add+document"),
       name='go-to-direct-download')
```

**Issue :**

If I write in my url : `http://localhost:8000/freepub/direct/download/PUBSD15-FR-PDF`

The redirection is : `http://localhost:8000/freepub/home?DocumentChoice=(?P<code>[%5Cw%5C.-]+)&DocumentSelected=Add+document`

How I could take into account the `code` in my url instead of `(?P<code>[%5Cw%5C.-]+)` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass the `RedirectView` for that:

```
# app/views.py

from django.http import QueryDict

class MyRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        q = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        q['DocumentChoice'] = self.kwargs['code']
        q['DocumentSelected'] = 'Add document'
        return 'http://localhost:8000/freepub/home?{}'.format(q.urlencode())
```

and then use it as:

```
url(
    r'^freepub/direct/download/(?P<code>[\w\.-]+)/', 
    MyRedirectView.as_view(),
   name='go-to-direct-download'
),
```

It would however be advisable to obtain the URL of the redirect by the name of the view, for example with [**`reverse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), since now the URL is hardcoded and if you later deploy your application, or change the hostname, it will result in wrong redirects.

Furthermore in Django one typically does not pass much data through GET parameters, so perhaps it is better to make a view, and encode that part in the URL path, instead of the querystring.

Comment: I will try your solution, then I will edit my code in order to change GET parameters to POST right ? Anyway thank you with your answer and I'll be back if it works or not ;)

Comment: @Ducky: typically one uses just the path, like you did here with the URL. The POST parameters are typically used for forms.

Comment: Do you think it's a bad way to follow my process with your answer ? Your answer works fine !

Comment: @Ducky: no, not per se, it's more that it is a bit "*un*-django", that is not per se a huge problem. The only issue that might arise from it, is that not all libraries, etc. are designed to handle this. But that's not a "direct" problem.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help ! It's a great answer as always and now my application works pretty fine on this point. Thank you !